# "brew install python" installs 3.9. Why not 3.10?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

My understanding is that "brew install python" installs the latest version of python. Why isn't it pulling 3.10? 3.10 is marked as a stable release.

I can install 3.10 with "brew install python@3.10 just fine and can update my PATH so that python and pip point to the right versions. But I am curious why "brew install python" its not installing 3.10.

My other understanding is that 3.10 is directly compatible with the M1 chips so that is why I want 3.10.

Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: You can install it, and adjust PATH so that it works, but it is not being installed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Henry Schreiner have specified now Python 3.10 is the new default in Brew. Thx for pointing it

--- Obsolete ---
The "python3" formula is still 3.9 in the brew system
check the doc here:
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.9#default

The latest version of the formula for 3.9 also support apple silicon.

If you want to use python3.10 you need to run as you described brew install python@3.10

The reason why 3.9 is still the official python3 formula is that generally user using the vanilla python3 are not looking for the latest revision but the more stable. in some months the transition will done.

Comment: It has now changed, as of August 2, 2022: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.10 & https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/b3dc47a6ecd533444e1461c8b3ec7104a8296cf4

Answer (score 10):

Python@3.10 is currently [*keg-only*](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#what-does-keg-only-mean), which means 3.10 is not the default version yet. You can see a message stating this by typing on the terminal: `brew info python@3.10`:

> python@3.10 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, 
> because this is an alternate version of another formula.

The migration tasks are not yet all done as of July 2022. You can see the latest situation and the details on GitHub: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/87075

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: It has now changed, as of August 2, 2022: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.10 & https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/b3dc47a6ecd533444e1461c8b3ec7104a8296cf4